# Drawn 3D prism on tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-3d

What is the best strategy to recreate this figure in tikz? I would like to add some color gradient to the red "triangular" region (darker at the bottom and lighter on top). Also, the larger side of that region should be slightly curved, as is shown in the picture. [image]

Comment: I'd use `tikz-3dplot` along with the `3d` library. The shading is easy, `top color=white,bottom color=red` or something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While some may be able to uniquely determine the 3d coordinates from such a screen shot, I cannot, so I had to guess. Given some 3d coordinates, it is straightforward to draw things using `tikz-3dplot`. The color gradient can be achieved with basic shading syntax.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,angles,quotes}
\definecolor{prbright}{RGB}{222,233,233}
\definecolor{prtop}{RGB}{192,217,221}
\definecolor{prdark}{RGB}{170,197,194}
\definecolor{prleft}{RGB}{178,200,202}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-12}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join=miter]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{8}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.6*\w,0,0.2*\h)}]
   \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
   \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
   \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
  \end{scope} 
  \draw[fill=prbright] (0,-\w/2,-\h) coordinate (btip) -- (-\w/2,-\w/2,0) coordinate (bl) 
  --  (\w/2,-\w/2,0) coordinate (br) --  cycle;
  \draw[fill=prleft]  (btip) -- (0,\w/2,-\h) coordinate (ftip) 
  -- (-\w/2,\w/2,0) coordinate (fl) -- (bl) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=prdark]  (btip) -- (ftip) 
  -- (\w/2,\w/2,0) coordinate (fr) -- (br) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=prtop]  (bl) -- (fl) --  (fr) -- (br) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,dashed] (0,4,-5) coordinate(A) -- (0,4,7);
  \draw[line width=2mm,-latex,red] (-2,6,-2) coordinate(C) -- (0,4,0) coordinate
  (B)  pic [draw,-,line width=0.6pt,red,angle radius=1cm,"$\alpha$",angle
  eccentricity=1.2] 
  {angle = C--B--A};
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=4,transform shape]
   \draw[red,thick,latex-] (3,1) node[black,above right]{$k_x$} -| (0,6);
   \draw[red,thick,top color=white,bottom color=red!80,middle color=red!20] 
    (2,1) -| (0,5) to[out=-90,in=135] cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]